# i'm stuck in converting song details to string

Tags: c#, string, struct, textbox, attributes

I wrote the code below:
(song is a struct)

```
private void get_attribute(string file)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[128];
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
        fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.Read(b, 0, 128);
        Song song = new Song();
        song.Singer= Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);
        song.Album= Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);
        song.Title= Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
        string a = song.Singer + song.Album + song.Title;
        textBox1.AppendText(a);
    }
```

But this only shows the Singer in the text box.
I want something like the text below in text box:
Singer:...      Album:...      Title:...
 [image]
The picture above is screenshot of the variable watches.
I also can't remove the '\0' from the strings using the "trunc" method.

Comment: You can remove 0x00 in this way song.Singer.Trim('\0'). Needed text you can get by string a = string.Format("Singer: {0}, Album: {1}, Title: {2}", song.Singer, song.Album, song.Title). Do you write the data into the file?

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan thx mate,it's done. i didn't get your question.can u explain?!

Comment: So, if you need serialize something you can use [JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm), [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or at least [binary serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but not do it by hand. If it just for getting skills with File, Streams, it's ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trim the termination char from your strings:

```
    string album = "Saz Single\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    string singer = "Bahram\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    string title = "saz\0\0\0";

    album = album.Trim('\0');
    singer = singer.Trim('\0');
    title = title.Trim('\0');

    string a = album + " " + singer + " " + title;
```

Ideally you would put that functionality in a method in your Song class! Or even better override the ToString() method of your Song class to return what you need.